# HTML to PostScript Conversion

Tags: c#, .net, postscript

I'm searching for a free component or library that could convert HTML to PostScript ( .ps file format ). I'm using .Net framework 1.1. Any one have experience with situation like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the HTML viewer control and print the html to a PostScript printer that outputs to a file. Not very elegant, but it would work. 
I think there are unix tools that does this, so you might find a windows port for one of them and use it via Process.Start.