# How can I create EPS files in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vector-graphics, eps

How can I create EPS files in C#?  Are there any opensource libraries available or do I have to resort to [the spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/postscript/pdfs/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf) and do it by hand?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same principle as I suggested in the HTML to Postscript question here: [html-to-postscript-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238217/html-to-postscript-conversion#238236)

It is clumsy to set up, but once it is done it works quite well. If you don't have a printer driver that creates EPS files you can download some of the freeware pdf creator printer drivers. I believe some of these allow you to create EPS files as well.

Answer (score 2):

The cairo library http://www.cairographics.org generate all kinds of graphical formats, svf, pdf or ps for instance, and it has bindings for c# I think.