# Looking for a .NET library for generating vector graphics files

Tags: .net, vector-graphics

Could someone recommend me a **.NET** library for generating these vector graphics files: SVG, EPS, PS, PDF, WMF, EMF?

I have found a good library for java: http://java.freehep.org/vectorgraphics/ but I would very appreciate it for **.NET**

Many thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

[This one only supports SVG](http://svg.codeplex.com/)

And there's a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525421/drawing-svg-in-net-c) that just asks about SVG.  I don't really know of any library that supports all of those formats.

You may have to find multiple libraries that support each (one for EPS/PS, one for PDF, one for WMF/EMF) as well.

**edit**:

- [EMF/WMF can be had from GDI+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152729/gdi-c-how-to-save-an-image-as-emf)
- PDF:  [Report.NET](http://report.sourceforge.net/)
- [a few suggestions from SO for EPS/PS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243068/how-can-i-create-eps-files-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [.NET bindings](http://www.cairographics.org/bindings/)  to the [Cairo library](http://www.cairographics.org/) but it isn't a 100% managed solution obviously.